# Read & delete from mongodb with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, mongodb, multithreading, pymongo, python-multiprocessing

I have a mongodb with a collection `incoming` and a collection `target`. A worker process currently is doing the following (simplified) :

```
def worker(number):
    incomings = db.incoming.find()
    buffersize=5
    readcounter=0
    for incoming in incomings:
        readcounter+=1
        documentToInsert={'keyfield':incoming["keyfield"], +other fields after some treatments...}
        documentsToInsert.append(incoming)
        documentToDelete={'_id':incoming["_id"]}
        documentsToDelete.append(documentToDelete)
        if readcounter >= readbuffer:
            readcounter=0
            db.incoming.remove({'_id': { '$in': [ObjectId(docs["_id"]) for docs in documentsToDelete]}})
            db.target.insert_many([docs for docs in documentsToInsert],ordered=False)
```

Of course the remove and the insert_many statements are surrounded by `try/except`.

As the data is coming in faster than it gets processed by the/one worker, I need to become faster, for example by spawning it over all cpus, which should happen anyways in order to be efficient. I'm doing that via the following code:

```
if __name__== "__main__":
    procs=[]
    number=0
    for cpu in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        procs.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (number,)))
        number+=1
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    print("=====================FIN=========================")
```

The problem is that while one thread is reading `buffersize` documents, the other threads get the same documents, resulting in a dilemma that only one thread does successful inserts into `target`, the other threads are producing duplicate key exceptions. That effect renders only one process useful. Without multithreading, the remove/insert_many combo is working fine and I can easily work with higher buffersizes.

I thought about inserting data into `incoming` with an additional field in order to qualify the worker `number`, but that is taking additional disk space and eats up additional processing, plus, at the time of generation, I do not know how many workers will be working on the data.

I've already tried to sleep a random time in each thread, but that is totally unpredictable and doesn't prevent errors per se.

What can I do in order to make all threads treating distinct data?

Comment: Have you considered something like RabbitMQ? This would allow you to decouple the incoming messages speed from the processing speed.

Comment: You mean something like: one thread is only reading and is feeding the other threads with documents to process? Sounds interesting, especially as it's only one reader instead of many, which solves a) reading distinct and b) reserving resources for many readers. With *mq (I prefer 0mq) the number of readers is basically unlimited. I'll give it a try. Thanks for this idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @[Belly Buster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10490683/belly-buster) for the idea of decoupling the treatments by using *MQ. I've solved it by using ZeroMQ, which is brokerless, but in this case, I've implemented a load balancing broker, based on the [Load balancing broker example for ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:lbbroker). The client is reading from the database while the workers are working on the entries which they get by ZeroMQ. I've tried to put some comprehensive comments into the code in order to make a few points clear. The code is missing a few utility classes which I've written and which are not part of this solution; this code is just to answer the question in the hope that anybody finds it useful.

```
"""
Original Author: Brandon Carpenter (hashstat) <brandon(dot)carpenter(at)pnnl(dot)gov>
This code was part of the ZeroMQ Tutorial and implements the Load-balancing broker pattern.
Modified by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2226028/michael
"""

from __future__ import print_function

import multiprocessing
import zmq
import io
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time
from pprint import pprint
import ast
import json
from bson.json_util import dumps
from datetime import datetime
from PairConfig import PairConfig
from PairController import PairController
import ctypes
import sys
from random import randint

NBR_CLIENTS = 1
NBR_WORKERS = 3

# Load the configuration file
# this is a configuration class which is not documented here
pairConfig=PairConfig("verify.ini")

# multiprocessing shared variables setup
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
insertbuffer=manager.list()
deletebuffer=manager.list()
totalcounter=multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_int,0)

def client_task(ident):
    try:
        """Basic request-reply client using REQ socket."""
        client = MongoClient(pairConfig.config.get('db','url'))
        db=client.databasename
        socket = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.identity = u"Client-{}".format(ident).encode("ascii")
        socket.connect("ipc://frontend.ipc")

        while True:
            incomings = db.incoming.find()
            # this makes it safe(r) to run this on different nodes
            incomings.skip(randint(randint(1,500),randint(5000,500000)))
            for incoming in incomings:
                pair = {'primarykey' : incoming["primarykey"], 'value' : incoming["value"]}
                # Send request, get reply
                socket.send_string(b"%s" % pair)
                reply = socket.recv()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nexit client")

def worker_task(ident,insertbuffer,deletebuffer,mylock):
    try:
        """Worker task, using a REQ socket to do load-balancing."""
        socket = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.identity = u"Worker-{}".format(ident).encode("ascii")
        socket.connect("ipc://backend.ipc")

        socket.send(b"READY")

        # this is a helper class which is not documented here
        pairController=PairController(pairConfig)
        while True:
            address, empty, request = socket.recv_multipart()
            with totalcounter.get_lock():
                totalcounter.value+=1
            dictToInsert = ast.literal_eval(request.encode("ascii"))
            dictToInsert["last_checked"]=datetime.now()
            insertbuffer.append(dictToInsert)
            deletebuffer.append(dictToInsert["primarykey"])
            # ... do some timely treatment here - a lot of variable time gets burned here ...
            # result will be result1 and result2, for the sake of simplification I will fill it with random numbers here
            result1=randint(1,10)
            result2=randint(1,10)
            sys.stdout.write("%s %s insertbuffer: %d, deletebuffer: %d, totalcounter: %d, b: %s, r: %s            \r" % (socket.identity.decode("ascii"),dictToInsert["primarykey"],len(insertbuffer),len(deletebuffer),totalcounter.value,result1,result2))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            # readbuffer comes from an ini file ... I chose 500 for now
            if len(insertbuffer[:]) >= int(pairConfig.config.get('verify','readbuffer')) and ident==0:
                mylock.acquire()
                # these 2 methods are inside a class pairController which is not documented here,
                # it's basically one method for insert_many() and one method for remove(), 
                # each time with the respective buffer as a filter
                pairController.storePairs("history",insertbuffer[:])
                pairController.deletePairs("history",deletebuffer[:])
                # this empties the buffers for all filters:
                insertbuffer[:]=[]
                deletebuffer[:]=[]
                mylock.release()
            socket.send_multipart([address, b"", b"ok"])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nexit worker")

def main():
    """Load balancer main loop."""
    # Prepare context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    frontend.bind("ipc://frontend.ipc")
    backend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    backend.bind("ipc://backend.ipc")

    # Start background tasks
    mylock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    def start(task, *args):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, args=args)
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()
    for i in range(NBR_CLIENTS):
        start(client_task, i)
    for i in range(NBR_WORKERS):
        start(worker_task, i, insertbuffer, deletebuffer, mylock)

    # Initialize main loop state
    count = NBR_CLIENTS
    workers = []
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    # Only poll for requests from backend until workers are available
    poller.register(backend, zmq.POLLIN)

    while True:
        sockets = dict(poller.poll())

        if backend in sockets:
            # Handle worker activity on the backend
            request = backend.recv_multipart()
            worker, empty, client = request[:3]
            if not workers:
                # Poll for clients now that a worker is available
                poller.register(frontend, zmq.POLLIN)
            workers.append(worker)
            if client != b"READY" and len(request) > 3:
                # If client reply, send rest back to frontend
                empty, reply = request[3:]
                frontend.send_multipart([client, b"", reply])
                count -= 1

        if frontend in sockets:
            # Get next client request, route to last-used worker
            client, empty, request = frontend.recv_multipart()
            worker = workers.pop(0)
            backend.send_multipart([worker, b"", client, b"", request])
            if not workers:
                # Don't poll clients if no workers are available
                poller.unregister(frontend)

    # Clean up
    backend.close()
    frontend.close()
    context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nexit main")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment I think a message broker using something like RabbitMQ is best for your use case. With RabbitMQ and similar message brokers (I've not used 0mq) you don't need to feed other threads, just start up as many threads as you need, each subscribes, and the broker will deliver up the messages in turn.